# jQuery val for dates results in empty string for some dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a most peculiar problem. Not sure if I stumbled upon a bug or if it's a culture problem.

What I'm trying to do is calculate elapsed days between two dates. This work quite nicely for the most part. But for some dates `$(date).val()` returns an empty string. Not sure why.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="dates">
    <li>
        <input type="date" class="date" max="2014-07-30" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="date" class="date" max="2014-07-30" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

The max attribute is always todays date. I just haven't added the calculation for it.

jQuery/Javascript:

```
var secondToLastRow = list.find('li:nth-last-child(2)');
var lastRow = list.find('li:nth-last-child(1)');

var secondToLastRowDateString = secondToLastRow.find('.date').val();
var secondToLastRowDate = new Date(Date.parse(secondToLastRowDateString));

var lastRowDateString = lastRow.find('.date').val();
var lastRowDate = new Date(Date.parse(lastRowDateString));

var days = (secondToLastRowDate - lastRowDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

As stated before this works, but, for some dates it returns empty string and therefore the calculation gets a NaN result.

I prepared a jsfiddle for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/52CPp/

Try inputing whatever you want at first, then try using 2014-02-30 as the first date and it stops working.

I'm in Sweden using Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m

Does anyone else have the same problem? Is it a culture problem? A bug?

Tried it in IE10 and the problem can't be reproduced there.

Kind regards, 
Robin

Comment: 2014-02-30 is not a valid date as February has only 28 days in 2014...
I suggest you to add a check before "calculate"

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely correct, how did I miss that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethink like this:

```
var secondToLastRowDate = new Date(Date.parse(secondToLastRowDateString));
    if (isNaN(secondToLastRowDate)==true)
    {
        alert("First date is not valid!");
        return;
    }
```

[Here's my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52CPp/2/)